# AutomaticDataLossException thrown after initial migration runs in EF 6 in SQL Server but not MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

*Background info:
I am about to start a new project written in C# (vs2015) which will be using Entity Framework 6 within its DAL. One of the core requirements is that the system must be able to run against either SQL Server, Azure SQL server, MySQL or Oracle as chosen by the user simply changing the connection string in the web.config.
So prior to the project kick-off I am trying to get more familiar with Entity Framework as I have not used it outside of a few tutorials before.*

I have written a small proof of concept app, the purpose of which is to determine how I can use EF to quickly swap a web api to use a different underlying DB. For the PoC I am using SQL Server express v12 and MySQL v5.6, C#, Entity Framework 6 via a code first approach.

I have hit a road block with my PoC, I am seeing different behaviour when running against MySQL compared to when I am running against SQL Server. I am using the following EF context:

```
  <context type="POC.Core.Api.DataAccessLayer.SchoolContext, POC.Core.Api" disableDatabaseInitialization="false">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[POC.Core.Api.DataAccessLayer.SchoolContext,  POC.Core.Api], [POC.Core.Api.Migrations.Configuration, POC.Core.Api]], EntityFramework"></databaseInitializer>        
  </context>
```

I have two migration scripts, one which is the initial creation and another which just adds a property to an object.

I have some test data being created in the seed method in the configuration class which looks like this (:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        this.SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(WeldOffice.Core.Api.DataAccessLayer.SchoolContext context)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
            ...
    };
```

Both my MySQL and SQL servers do not yet have the database present at all yet.

As I want the user to be able to specify the DB I am relying on in-code methods to create the DB structure etc.

Given this scenario, my understanding is that the following occurs when the db context is first hit when running the app:

1. Check for existence of the database - it is not present so it will be created.
2. Check if the initial creation script has been run - it has not so run it.
3. Check if the add property script has been run - it has not so run it.
4. Run the seed method to ensure data is present and correct.

In MySQL this all works as expected, the database is created, the tables set up and the data populated. The two migration scripts are listed in the migration table.

In SQL Server, steps 1,2,3 all work and the database is created and the tables set up. The two migration scripts are listed in the migration table. However, step 4 is not run, the Seed method is never hit and instead a AutomaticDataLossException exception is thrown.

If I set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true then step 4 also works and everything is as expected. But, I would not really want to have AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed set to true and don't see why this is necessary in SQL server but not MySQL. Why is this the case? I feel I am missing something fundamental.

Please keep in mind this is just a proof on concept, in production there will be no seed data anyway, and I would rather a dba create the db via sql scripts etc.